# Can't compile my C++ ros_nxt publisher

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new in programming, so i'm trying to make my own publisher to the topic wich controls the motors of my NXT, so here is the code that i have written.I'm not sure if it is the correct thing that i need to control the motors, but i can't compile it.

```
#include <nxt_msgs/JointCommand.h>
#include <ros/ros.h>
        
           template<class M> ros::Publisher ros::NodeHandle::advertise(const     nxt_msgs::JointCommand, uint32_t, bool)
    
        int main(int argc, char **argv)
    
    {
        ros::init(argc, argv, "JointCommand");
    
        ros::NodeHandle n;
        ros::Publisher pub = n.advertise<nxt_msgs::>("JointCommand", 1);
        ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
    
        int test=1;
        nxt_msgs::JointCommand c;
        c = nxt_msgs::JointCommand();
        test = c.effort;
    
        pub.publish(c);
    
        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();
    
        return 0;
    }
```

when i try to make my package it gives me the following error :

```
/ros_workspace/NXT/src/rc.cpp:6:1: error: expected initializer before ‘int’
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53182/can%27t-compile-my-c++-ros_nxt-publisher/) by [Saho](https://answers.ros.org/users/4033/saho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error seems to be caused by the template before int main(). I'm not sure what you're trying to do with that line...it looks like a function prototype without a semicolon. The template also doesn't make sense. If the prototype was valid, you'd also want to add a semicolon at the end to terminate

---

Originally posted by [mirzashah](https://answers.ros.org/users/3576/mirzashah/) with karma: 1209 on 2013-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1